# How do you parse the sentence "The lamp by which she read the book grew dimmer."?

Tags: grammar, sentence, syntactic-analysis

How do you parse the following sentence?

> The lamp by which she read the book grew dimmer.

My friend says that "by which she read the book" qualifies "the lamp". So, it would basically mean "The lamp that she was using to read grew dimmer."

For some reason, I comprehend the sentence as
"The lamp that she was near while reading the book grew dimmer." Can it go both ways, or...?

Also, about the usage of "grew dimmer" there, should it be "dimmed" instead? Thanks.

Comment: How else would you parse it, if not as your friend suggests?

Comment: I was just wondering if it was proper/or if there was a better way to write the sentence.

Comment: Yes, very good. You've spotted an ambiguity. Your friend interprets *by* as a preposition of agency: *The lamp by means of which....* You interpret *by* as a preposition of place: *The lamp alongside of which....*

Comment: I am not following. You do not read a book *by means* of a lamp. You can only read it by means of your eyes (or your fingers if you're blind). You can illuminate it by means of a lamp, and you can weigh it down by means of a lamp, and maybe you can even poke a hole in it by means of a lamp, but you cannot read it by means of a lamp. The lamp does not do the reading. No ambiguity possible in this particular case. To read something by a lamp clearly means near the lamp and nothing else.

Comment: @RegDwigнt That's what I presumed. Would "The lamp, by which she was using to help her read the book, grew dimmer." be a way to correct the sentence? Also, my friend argues that what you said was correct because it would be like saying you can't vote with a system or a system can't vote in the context of "A system by which people could vote by telephone."

Comment: @RegDwigнt I hear what you say but I disagree. My experience is that people often say things like *I was reading by candlelight*. And I recollect that there is a certain contributor to this site who invariably argues that if people say it then it must be valid English!

Answer (score 1):

Whichever of the alternative readings you employ, yours or your friend's (both of which are possible), the parsing is no different. *...by which she read the book* remains as an adjectival clause qualifying *lamp*.

The only difference is in the meaning of *by*. Is it *by* meaning *by means of*, or *by* meaning *near*.

The main verb is *grew*. But the sentence would benefit greatly from parenthetical commas after *lamp* and *book*.

***The lamp, by which she read the book, grew dimmer***.

Comment: My friend argues "by" in "by which" always means "by means of". If the sentence was, "The lamp she read the book by grew dimmer." the "by" could mean either, but not the case with "by which."

Comment: The problem with the location reading, for this specific example, is the "grew dimmer" part.  If "by the lamp" means "next to the lamp", you'd imagine that she was reading by daylight and just happened to be next to the lamp.  Presumably, the lamp was turned off.  But in that case, the lamp couldn't "grow dimmer".

Comment: @AliceNykaza Would your friend therefore argue that the phrase *the lamppost by which I was standing* is invalid?

Comment: ... To do so wouldn't be too bright. /  'The lamp by which she read the book grew dimmer.' would pragmatically be interpreted as having the agency rather than the locative reading without further context. It would be an error (though not a grammatical one) (arguably worse, I'd point out to grammar-worshippers) not to indicate if this default sense was not the one intended (unless the ambiguity was intended, say in a humorous context).